# Indicator A Group of Function Calls is Complete in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to know when Excel is done calculating a batch of functions?
For example, if I have a function, myFunc() and I call it 10 times in one sitting, is there a way programmatically to know that the 10 calls are done?  The solution needs to be flexible enough for any amount of function calls.  So if I call 10 times in one sitting on Monday then 30 times at once on Tuesday, the solution is able to recognize the end of all my calls and let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking UDFs here? Otherwise, simply call the function from a sub, and use BEEP or MSGBOX.

Comment: How do you wish to be notified? There are a variety of notification methods.

Comment: @jeffreyweir yes, a UDF.

Comment: @QHarr , I'm not sure what my options are, so I will have a look at those functions.  I have a UDF function that gets some data from an API and puts the response content in a dictionary.  I want to know when all those functions are done updating the dictionary.  The end user is expected to make multiple queries at once, so I do not want to be updated at the end of each individual function call, but all of them.

Comment: UDFs can end up recalculating at other times so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call this function as a UDF. Instead, call it from another sub, store the answer in an array, then write the array to the worksheet, and use Beep or MsgBox to tell the user you're done.